# Steps to to handing off designs to engineers

Tags: website-design, sketch-app, workflow, design-process, adobe-xd

I work as a UX/UI Designer at a small startup right now. My background is in design with some front end work. I'm not sure our process for handing off files to developers is the most efficient and feel that I am constantly going through revisions or miscommunication with our work.

I have a pretty big interview with a new company coming up and wondering what others have been doing in terms of process for working with engineers and handing off files. I would love to go into this interview filled with as much knowledge as I can get rather than be blinded or oblivious due to a lack of experience with other engineers or designer/engineer pairing. Any tools, workflows, habits, processes, negative experiences, etc. (or even reading material on Medium) would be appreciated.

Comment: Kind of depends upon the work being completed and the engineers themselves. Every workflow may be different.

Comment: I am an engineer by first training. Take heart, those are good people. You are not writing enough about the existing process of "handing off": Do you ever meet those people? Go and meet. Do you phone? Or just e-mail files and fill-in forms? Meet those engineers half-way comm-wise, learn their language, explain your perspective, respect their techical constraints, LISTEN to what they tell you and try to help them helping you, think about who is customer/provider in your setup, who is paying whom and what does it mean, what does your supervisor have to say about the setup, consider common sense.

Comment: Hi jamiechalski. While your question is interesting, it's a bit unclear at the moment. Could you maybe [edit] it and tell us a bit more about the process? Also, you talk about engineers, but also developers. Those are quite different roles. Which of the two is it, or is it both?

Answer (score -1):

This will depend on the tool being used to create designs. We use Sketch and have found that uploading a prototype to [Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/) causes less confusion between designers and developers/engineers.

Invision allows you to share clickable prototypes - giving engineers a clear vision of the flow of your application or website, and it also has an "Inspect Mode" that gives a deeper breakdown of elements such as fonts, colors and other css styles. As you can imagine, this is extremely useful and saves a lot of time in terms of mis-communication and going back and forth with assets.

[image: Invision Inspect Mode]

I would, however, still recommend supplying any developer/engineer with a professional stylesheet (on top of Invision) as well as any graphics/icons they require.

Comment: Hi Christelle, Welcome to Graphic Design at stackexchange. Please edit to expand your answer to explain **how** this causes less confusion. More detail is very helpful for those with less experience than you have in this area.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. I am new here and still getting the hang of things.  I will update my post accordingly.